# Why mass uploads cancel out scores calculated by Apex code?

Tags: apex, process-builder

We recently implemented this Apex code "Account Grading Method" (attached below) in our system. When an account record is created or edited, a process in the Process Builder calls the Apex code to calculate the account grade. It calculates the score of an account based on the input of a group of fields called Account Intelligence fields and returns the result to a number field called "Account Overall Grade".

The problem is whenever we mass update accounts using an upload (like API Data Loader) or via nightly API calls, the score of the Account Overall Grade gets zeroed out as a result when it shouldn't be.

For example, if you try mass updating the "Website" field on a number of accounts, the process in Process Builder is triggered to call the Account Grading Method, and that method zeroes out, which shouldn't, the Account Overall Grade on those accounts, which were not zero.

When we tried to mass update accounts in list view, the score zeroed out as well. For example, we took an account list view and selected a bunch of records to do a mass in-line editing of one of the Account Intelligence fields, the "Account Overall Grade" field zeroed out.

Any idea on how we can continue to be able to mass update accounts without this happening, or what the issue is?  The person who developed this account grading process and the code had left.  Any help would be much much appreciated!

My apologies this is a lot of code. Thank you for your patience.

**AccountGradingMethod**

```
 public with sharing class AccountGradingMethod {

    public static void AccountGrading(Set<String> setAcctGradingIds) {
        List<Account> lstAGS = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> lstUpdateAcct = new List<Account>();
        Map<String, Field_Value__mdt> mapFlds = new Map<String, Field_Value__mdt>();
        String strSOQLAcct;
        String strSOQLAcctGrade;
        Set<String> setFlds = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> setFldName = new Set<String>();
        String strScore;
        Decimal maxPossScore = 0;
        Decimal numberFlds = 0;

        strSOQLAcctGrade = 'SELECT Id';
        for(Field_Value__mdt fn:[SELECT Id, Field_Score_or_Multiplier__c, Picklist_API_Value__c, Use_Greater_then_or_Less_then__c, 
                                        Field_Name__r.Field_API_Name__c, Field_Name__r.Object__c, Field_Name__r.Type_of_Field__c,
                                        Greater_then__c, Less_then__c
                                    FROM Field_Value__mdt]){
            String mapKey;
            setFldName.add(fn.Field_Name__r.Field_API_Name__c);
            if(fn.Field_Name__r.Object__c == 'Account'){
                setFlds.add(fn.Field_Name__r.Field_API_Name__c);
            }
            if(fn.Use_Greater_then_or_Less_then__c){
                mapKey = fn.Field_Name__r.Field_API_Name__c + '-' + fn.Greater_then__c + '-' + fn.Less_then__c;
            }
            else{
                mapKey = fn.Field_Name__r.Field_API_Name__c + '-' + fn.Picklist_API_Value__c.deleteWhitespace();
            }
            mapFlds.put(mapKey, fn);
        }
        for(String f:setFlds){
            strSOQLAcctGrade += ', ' + f;
        }
        numberFlds = setFlds.size();
        strSOQLAcctGrade += ' FROM Account WHERE Id in :setAcctGradingIds';
        System.debug('strSOQLAcctGrade: ' + strSOQLAcctGrade);
        lstAGS = Database.query(strSOQLAcctGrade);
        strScore = System.Label.Max_Possible_Score;
        maxPossScore = Decimal.valueOf(strScore);

        for(Account ags:lstAGS){
            Decimal subTotal = 0;
            Decimal multiplier = 1;
            Decimal decTotal = 0;
            Decimal ecommTotal = 0;
            Decimal ecommMin = 0;
            Decimal ecommMax = 0;
            Decimal fldsPopulated = 0;
            Decimal precentComplete = 0;
            for(Field_Value__mdt fldVal:mapFlds.values()){
                String value;
                Decimal score = 0;
                Boolean skip = false;
                String fld = fldVal.Field_Name__r.Field_API_Name__c;
                String strKey;
                Decimal decValue = 0;
                if(setFldName.contains(fld)){
                    if(fldVal.Field_Name__r.Object__c == 'Account'){
                        value = String.valueOf(ags.get(fld));
                        if(value != '' && value != 'null' && value != null){
                            value = value.deleteWhitespace();
                            if(fldVal.Use_Greater_then_or_Less_then__c){
                                decValue = Decimal.valueOf(value);
                                System.debug('decValue: ' + decValue);
                                if(fldVal.Greater_then__c != null && fldVal.Less_then__c != null){
                                    if(fldVal.Greater_then__c > decValue && fldVal.Less_then__c < decValue){
                                     System.debug('if 1 fldVal.Less_then__c: ' + fldVal.Less_then__c);
                                        strKey = fld + '-' + fldVal.Greater_then__c + '-' + fldVal.Less_then__c;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        skip = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(fldVal.Greater_then__c == null && fldVal.Less_then__c != null){
                                    if(fldVal.Less_then__c > decValue){
                                     System.debug('if 2 fldVal.Less_then__c: ' + fldVal.Less_then__c);
                                        strKey = fld + '-' + fldVal.Greater_then__c + '-' + fldVal.Less_then__c;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        skip = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(fldVal.Greater_then__c != null && fldVal.Less_then__c == null){
                                    System.debug('if 3 fldVal.Greater_then__c : ' + fldVal.Greater_then__c );
                                    if(fldVal.Greater_then__c < decValue){
                                        strKey = fld + '-' + fldVal.Greater_then__c + '-' + fldVal.Less_then__c;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        skip = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (!fldVal.Use_Greater_then_or_Less_then__c){
                                strKey = fldVal.Field_Name__r.Field_API_Name__c + '-' + value;
                            }
                            if(!String.isBlank(strKey) && mapFlds.get(strKey) != null){
                                setFldName.remove(fld);
                                score = mapFlds.get(strKey).Field_Score_or_Multiplier__c;
                            }
                            if(score != null){
                                if(fld.startsWithIgnoreCase('e-commerce solutions')){
                                    skip = true;
                                    ecommTotal = ecommTotal + score;
                                    if(ecommMax<score){
                                        ecommMax = score;
                                    }
                                    if(ecommMin>score){
                                        ecommMin = score;
                                    }
                                }
                                if(fldVal.Field_Name__r.Type_of_Field__c == 'Score' && !skip){
                                    System.debug('fld: ' + fld);
                                    System.debug('Score: ' + score);
                                    subTotal = subTotal + score;
                                }
                                if(fldVal.Field_Name__r.Type_of_Field__c == 'Multiplier' && !skip){
                                    System.debug('fld: ' + fld);
                                    System.debug('multiplier: ' + score);
                                    multiplier = multiplier * score;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            fldsPopulated = fldsPopulated + 1;
                            setFldName.remove(fld);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(ecommTotal>=0){
                subTotal = subTotal + ecommMax;
            }
            else{
                subTotal = subTotal + ecommMin;
            }
            if(fldsPopulated == numberFlds){
                precentComplete = 100;      }
            else{
                precentComplete = ((numberFlds - fldsPopulated)/numberFlds)*100;
            }
            System.debug('subtotal: ' +  subTotal);
            subTotal = (subTotal/maxPossScore)*100;
            System.debug('subtotal after: ' +  subTotal);
            System.debug('multiplier: ' + multiplier);
            decTotal = subTotal*multiplier;
            System.debug('decTotal: ' + decTotal );
            Account a = new Account();
                a.Id = ags.Id;
                a.Account_Overall_Grade__c = decTotal;
                a.Percent_Complete__c = precentComplete;
            lstUpdateAcct.add(a);

        }
        if(lstUpdateAcct.size()>0){
            update lstUpdateAcct;
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountGradingFlowPluggin**

```
global class AccountGradingFlowPluggin {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Account Grading' description='')
    global static void AccountGrading (List<AccountGradingVariables> request) {
        Set<String> setAcctIds = new Set<String>();
        for(AccountGradingVariables ag: request){
            setAcctIds.add(ag.accountId);
        }
        AccountGradingMethod.AccountGrading(setAcctIds);
    }

    global class AccountGradingVariables{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String accountId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the user who does the bulk data changes have access to all the necessary field?

Comment: @Kasper, thank you for the response! And, yes, I believe so.

Comment: Sorry Tina, that was my only guess. I don't think there should be a reason why this doesn't work. What happens when you use the data loader to upload just one record?

Comment: Hi, @Kasper, when I use the data loader to just update one record, it works correctly.  When I do it with two records, the 1st record in the spreadsheet is uploaded correctly while the 2nd record is not, the Account Overall Grade for which is zeroed out. When I do it with 300 records, only three random records have their fields updated and the Account Overall Grade remains intact.  I don't feel like I can predict the behavior at all.

Comment: When you upload records with the dataloader you can set a batch size. All those batches are processed in one go. Apparently the processed batch size is 100 records. I'm guessing either the first or last processed record in a batch gets processed correctly. As a temporary fix you can set the batch size to 1 when uploading via the dataloader. This is slower than normal operation, but will allow  you to update your records. For a proper fix you'll have to figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Kasper, thank you sooo much!!!! The temporary fix works like a charm! I wonder if it has anything to do with the Process Builder bulkification limitations?

Comment: It does sound like PB bulk limitations.  You could try setting a debug log and doing the upload with normal batch size to see if any errors appear in the logs.

Comment: Tina, you're welcome, happy to help. @DavidCheng I could be wrong but doesn't every PB run as a separate process and without being bulkified? That would mean that Tina could only run into the governor limits when updating data in bulk. The only thing that I can think of right now that would cause this behavior is if there's actually a trigger that calls the accountGradingMethod.

Comment: @kaspar you're right, I was thinking of when PB runs its own update records bulk action, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @DavidCheng, Thank you for your reply!  My apologies for not being able to get back to you sooner.  I had been travelling the past few weeks for meetings. I did as you suggested and the debug log did not catch any errors.  I will work with someone internally on this account score code issues. Hopefully the person can spot the problem. Thank you!!!